# Api limit access to subscribers only

Tags: php, api, security, authentication, python-3.x

I have a vanilla `php` `api`(on a vds) and I want to make data coming from that api available to a few clients that are using a `python` app that's also written by me. That python app is running on my client/s pc. But now i'm facing a problem: that app can be "pirated".

How do I make sure that the access is limited to only my paid subscribers?

I know that "DRM" or copy protection won't work therefore I was thinking about using tokens that are only available 1 day. And each call will send an Authorization header and based on that the api can decide what to do.

```
private function check_authorization(){
    if(Server::exists('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')){
        $credentials = preg_split('/[\s:]/', trim(Server::get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')));

        //try to authenticate the user using those credentials

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I was thinking about binding those tokens to 1 IP/day but then there's the dynamic ip and the spoofing problem.

Also I was thinking about using something like `Steam` way to authenticate new devices for a user: new device? just send a 6 digits code trough email and ask the user to send it over to the api for confirmation. But if i can't identify the device, other than its ip it'll be pretty painful for those clients who happen to be less fortunate and have a dynamic ip.

Should i go as far as checking the operating system, maybe even get the mac and bind my tokens to those macs? Is that even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no match between a user—that is a physical person—and an IP address. The same person may have its IP address change on regular basis, even when using a PC. Similarly, multiple users may share the same IP address (for instance multiple persons working in the same company).

Operating system can be spoofed. So does the MAC address, which is relatively easy to change for a virtual machine.

If your goal is to protect your API, issue a certificate per user or use some other sort of authentication, similarly to the way it's done by every per-user API: Amazon AWS, Google APIs, Twilio, PayPal, etc.

What happens on client's machine is not your problem. If a hacker gains access to your user's PC and steals the certificate or credentials in order to access the API on behalf of your user, it's not your business: it belongs to the user to ensure the certificate or the credentials are kept safe. It belongs to you, on the other hand, to be able to reissue a new certificate rapidly once you're alerted that the previous one was stolen.

Comment: You mean i should issue a hash/key? If yes, how do i make sure that that user doesn't send that key to 10 of his...let's say friends?

Comment: Certificates are a better alternative, but yes, API keys would do the job as well. How to know the person won't share the keys? By (1) setting thresholds in terms of how many requests/resources the client can use during an hour/a day/a month, and (2) making extra usage a paid service.

Comment: Hmm...so then i should do this: save the first successful call for one dataset and block the access to further calls until my api is ready to provide another, new, never-called by that user, dataset?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things upfront. Log accesses to the API so you can see which users have unusual access patterns (widely dispersed IP locations, very high access frequency etc.) and talk to them if you notice something odd. Weigh your cost of implementing a scheme against the possible loss in case of pirating. Would your business suffer? If you've got just a few clients you probably don't need a solution designed for millions of users.

Comment: One additional idea related to the "friends" issue: you could offer a discount to existing clients who bring new customers. This makes it less attractive to "share" a license (especially when there is a risk of getting caught).

Comment: The point is that i would like to keep my business small...so yes my business would suffer and implementing a solution won't cost me anything but a little bit of time to code it. But most importantly i developed this software/business to practice and now that i'm gaining some ground i'm trying to learn new things, one of them being this access restriction.

Comment: At the end of the day i think i'll do it this way: one user id/token can request one dataset once. I'll log all those calls into a table(user id/token/timestamp/dataset id) and ...so on. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Sounds still pretty limiting. What if a user's download of a dataset is interrupted? Would they need to acquire a new token for another download attempt? Does acquiring a token cost something? Will they accept the inconvenience?

Comment: Ok so hear me out: let the user make unlimited calls for 1 minute/dataset. Save the call/s and bind the ip for each call. If the ip is different for more than, let's say, two calls something's going on. At the end of the day the app will make a report and block the users that didn't respect the terms of service(i don't like the "pay more for those extra calls" solution). Would that do it or even that is over engineering?

Comment: Actually unlimited calls/dataset and check at the end of the day and see how many times was a token used for each dataset?

Comment: It's you who will decide which measures to implement. If you feel more secure with a system that blocks users who seem to abuse your API then go for it. You know your users, and most likely have a good feel for how well-behaved they are.

Comment: Hmm, i will use daily tokens and check the traffic for each user/token and from there i'll see what i'll do. Thank you so much!